# Is using active and passive voice in a single sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, passive-voice, active-voice

Could you check following sentence? Indeed, I do not know whether using active and passive voice together in a single sentence is correct. Thanks for your help.

> Founded by Zadeh in 1965, fuzzy set theory **has advanced** in many diciplines and **has been investigated** from many aspects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no prohibition against using active and passive voice in the same sentence.  Your sentence is idiomatic and intelligible.